# Is it possible to render MathJax for chats in Android Web browser?

Tags: discussion, chat, mathjax, android

I have searched for it and found that I have to run a link like this ([RenderJax](http://javascript:(function()%7Bif(window.MathJax===undefined)%7Bvar%20script%20=%20document.createElement(%22script%22);script.type%20=%20%22text/javascript%22;script.src%20=%20%22https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML%22;var%20config%20=%20%27MathJax.Hub.Config(%7B%27%20%20%20%27extensions:%20[%22tex2jax.js%22],%27%20%20%20%27tex2jax:%20%7B%20inlineMath:%20[[%22$%22,%22$%22],[%22%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C(%22,%22%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C)%22]],%20displayMath:%20[[%22$$%22,%22$$%22],[%22%5C%5C%5C%5C[%22,%22%5C%5C%5C%5C]%22]],%20processEscapes:%20true%20%7D,%27%20%20%20%27jax:%20[%22input/TeX%22,%22output/HTML-CSS%22]%27%20%20%20%27%7D);%27%20%20%20%27MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();%27;if%20(window.opera)%20%7Bscript.innerHTML%20=%20config%7D%20else%20%7Bscript.text%20=%20config%7D%20document.getElementsByTagName(%22head%22)[0].appendChild(script);(doChatJax=function()%7Bwindow.setTimeout(doChatJax,1000);MathJax.Hub.Queue([%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub]);%7D)();%7Delse%7BMathJax.Hub.Queue([%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub]);%7D%7D)();))) which I found [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html). I have to bookmark this link and open it whenever I want to render MathJax in chat.

But the problem is whenever I open the bookmark, it opens in a new tab and keeps on loading forever. What should I do?

Comment: Thanks your answer is better than mine, I m deleting my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I succeeded to render MathJax for chats in an **Android** Browser. Here are the steps:

1. Go to play store and install [Opera mini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.mini.native).
2. After you install the app, open it and go to Bookmarks, Press the 3 dots in the top right corner, press New bookmark.
3. Paste the following javascript code in the field for URL.

```
javascript: (function() {
    if (window.MathJax === undefined) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML";
        var config = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({' + 'extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],' + 'tex2jax: { inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\\\\\\\\\\\(","\\\\\\\\\\\\)"]], displayMath: [["$$","$$"],["\\\\[","\\\\]"]], processEscapes: true },' + 'jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"]' + '});' + 'MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';
        if (window.opera) {
            script.innerHTML = config
        } else {
            script.text = config
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        (doChatJax = function() {
            window.setTimeout(doChatJax, 1000);
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
        })();
    } else {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
    }
})();
```

4. Type whatever the name you want. I prefer startJax.
5. Open your chat page, the chat won't be rendered yet.
6. Go to bookmarks, open you saved bookmark, Your chats will be rendered now.